# NodeJS - config.get() enviroment variable

Tags: node.js, express

I am following [this tutorial on users for an express app](https://medium.com/quick-code/handling-authentication-and-authorization-with-node-7f9548fedde8).

I got stuck at chapter `Running the application`.

I have set up the enviroment variable using `$env:myprivatekey = "test"`

I test the variable using `$env:myprivatekey`

```
test
```

The problem is that

```
config.get("myprivatekey");
```

is raising

```
    throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
    ^

Error: Configuration property "myprivatekey" is not defined
    at Config.get (C:\Users\misko\Documents\Projects\WeddingSallon\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:182:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\misko\Documents\Projects\WeddingSallon\app.js:6:8)       
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable from your current shell session? If not, try to export it. Also, here's more on setting environment variables https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables

Comment: Did you try just setting the variable (always in the same shell session) with  export myprivatekey = "test" ? I believe it may resolve the issue.

Comment: I set it right before I start the app. If I use command export I get export : "The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try    
again."

Answer (score 0):

Inside default.json you have used:

```
{
 "myprivatekey": "myprivatekey"
}
```

But you have to use it like:

```
module.exports = {
  myprivatekey: "myprivatekey"
};
```

Comment: This is a json file and not an express module, so he can't export it.